# `cv.glmnet` works in RStudio but not RScript

Tags: r

The following commands work fine in RStudio, but not RScript:

```
require(glmnet)
calibdata = read.csv("calibrationfile.csv")

xs = model.matrix(as.formula("targetvar~predictor1+predictor2)),calibdata)[,-1] # -1 discards intercept constant, glmnet has its own
ys = as.numeric(unlist(calibdata["targetvar"]))
fit=cv.glmnet(xs,ys)
```

The error message from RScript:

```
Error in is(x, "CsparseMatrix") : could not find function "new"
Calls: cv.glmnet -> glmnet -> elnet -> getcoef -> drop0 -> is
Execution halted
```

R version is 3.2.3 in both cases and glmnet version 2.0-2.

How can I get glmnet to work in RScript?

Comment: Should this perhaps be migrated to Stack Overflow? It does not seem to be on-topic here, so I don't think it should be reopened, but I wonder if it would benefit from migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RScript` has this "lovely" feature of not loading the (base package) methods for you.

So all you need here is an additional

```
  require(methods)
```

or

```
  suppressMessages(library(methods))
```

For what it is worth, the [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) command-line and scripting front-end to R that Jeff Horner and I wrote defaults to loading methods for you...

Comment: I met exactly the same problem. Script ran normally untill I did an update to the kernel of the system. it works fine now. Thanks Dirk.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, and found two possible workaround (just for a complement of @[Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)'s answer):

Well, I read somewhere that `--default-packages=methods,utils` needs to be passed to `Rscript` to work around this: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/190

OR,

Also, it seems, `Rscript` being missing the load of the `methods` package. This can also be fixed by calling `library('methods')` at the beginning of your script: https://github.com/dhimmel/elevcan/issues/1.

Hope this helps.