# How to pop up the graphics window from Rscript?

Tags: r, plot

I'm using Rscript to run a plot as follows:

```
x=1:10 
y=1:10 
plot(x,y)
```

I expect this code to popup a window with a graphic showing the plot when I run the code like this:

```
Rscript plot.R
```

The program finishes to completion, and the graphic does not appear, not even momentarily.  I know this code is right because it does produce a plot in the Rstudio GUI.

Does Rscript have a feature to popup that plot automatically on execution?

Comment: The interactive graphics devices are OS dependent. On Windows it's `windows`; on OSX it's `quartz`; on Linux, `x11`.

Comment: @42-, do you think it'd be a good idea to use `Sys.info()['sysname']` and then use appropriate device conditionally?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I think most of the code I have seen that does that sort of thing uses `.Platform$OS.type` or `.Platform$GUI`

Answer (score 16):

**Example 1: Pop up the graphics window directly from Rscript using `tcltk`**

Edit from 6 years in the future: tcltk used to be the standard for R display interface but now `tcltk` is depreciated.  Use Example 2:

```
library(tcltk)      #you have to install tcltk for your OS
x=1:10 
y=1:10 
windows()           #Use X11() or quartz() if on linux or mac.
plot(x,y)
prompt  <- "hit spacebar to close plots"
extra   <- "some extra comment"
capture <- tk_messageBox(message = prompt, detail = extra)
```

The above code presents the plot in a popup window and waits for you to press ok on the dialog.  If that doesn't work because `tcltk` or its interface between R and your screen doesn't work, you can do it manually from your terminal as follows by having R asking the OS to 'open the file for presentation':

**Example 2: Pop up the graphics window from Rscript using `browseURL`**

```
#Tested on R version 4.2.1
png("mygraphic.png")     #Create a png file
x = 1:10
print(x^2)
plot(x, x^2, 'o')        #Plot x on the horizontal and x^2 on the vertical
print("done")
dev.off()
browseURL("mygraphic.png")    #R uses the terminal to tell the 
                              #OS to open mygraphic.png
```

The above R code saves the png to disk as `mygraphic.png` and asks the operating system to open the file in the program designated for that filetype.  If it doesn't work open the file manually.  To change the program a .png file opens with, has to be done by going to to your OS's system settings which is dependent on your operating system.  I make a custom keymapping at the OS level for Alt-w to alt-F4 then I can edit the code, run it, pop the window, dismiss and get back to the editor, all in under 600 milliseconds without touching the mouse.

**Example 3: Pop up the graphic using `system()` terminal**

```
#Tested on R version 4.2.1 
png("mygif.png")     #Create a png file 
x = 1:10 
plot(x, x^5, 'o')        #Plot x on the horizontal and x^5 on the vertical 
dev.off() 

#replace the word 'animate' with your favorite paint/image/gif editor.
system("animate mygif.png")    #R uses the terminal to tell the 
                               #OS to open your image/gif
```

Example 3 is the best.  Expecting Rscript to be a display manager is doubleplusungood.

Comment: your second method is actually a nice workaround. But the first one does not work for me. The `library(tcltk)` returns [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875307/how-to-install-tcltk-in-r). Tried installing tcl-tk with homebrew but it di not help either.

Comment: Ok I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/2683). R needs to be installed with `brew reinstall r --with-openblas`.

Comment: @Foad `library("tcltk")` should work (`"tcltk"` instead of `tcltk`). Make sure you have the library installed by typing `install.packages("tcltk")` in the `R` prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented the pop-up graphics instead. Which is easy and neat no library needed.