# Batch File Produces Blank PNG Images

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I am running some plots on R. When I run the source code from RStudio, I get the output images as expected. However, when I run the source code from a **.bat** file, the output images are blank.

**runPlots.R**

```
dev.copy(png, "image.png")
dev.off()
```

**runPlots.bat**

```
@echo off
title Run plots
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\...\runPlots.R"
```

Is there something that I am missing here? Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: What is `image.png` ? It is created by R ? How ? Or is it already in your hard drive ? Are you sure of the working directory ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yup, created by R using plot.igraph() from library(igraph). And yes, I am very sure of the working directory because when I run the code directly in RStudio, the images are produced as expected in the said directory.

Comment: And if you do `png("image.png")` then `plot.igraph(....)` then `dev.off()` ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in graphics but I'm afraid the graphical device depends on the software (RStudio, Rgui,...). I don't know. I'm curious to see if my previous proposal works.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Wow it works like magic! Thanks! Could you please post that as the answer, with the explanation behind this?

Comment: Cool! I've learnt something too. Ok, I post an answer.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42544779/7816348 I suspect that dev.copy only works from interactive graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this:

```
png("image.png")
plot.igraph(....)
dev.off()
```

And this works.

#### Explanation:

When you do

```
plot.igraph(......) 
dev.copy(png, "image.png")
dev.off()
```

then `dev.copy` copies the image displayed by the graphical window of RStudio. That does not work in batch mode.

#### Other possibility:

Thanks to @Eumenedies's comment. You can open a graphical window with the command `windows()` on Windows and `x11()` on Linux. Then this code works when it is ran from a batch file:

```
windows()
plot(.......)
dev.copy(png, "image.png")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Does the `dev.copy` option work if you open an interactive plotting window before the `plot.igraph(...)` e.g. `windows()` on windows or `x11()` on linux?

Comment: @Eumenedies I'm not an expert in this domain but I think you need a graph displayed in a graphical window. You mean you want to include `x11()` in the batch file ? I don't know whether it works.It's quite possible.

Comment: Yes. The default plotting device for Rscript is PDF but, as you say, you need a graphical window for dev.copy.

Comment: @Eumenedies Yes, I have just tried and it works. But I think the solution I posted is better. Anyway I will edit my post to include this possibility.

Comment: Agreed. Your solution is the right way to do it if you only want the plot. The graphical device allows you to see the plot while the script is running and save it so it depends slightly on use case.

Comment: @Eumenedies Yes but you do not have the time to see the plot. It is immediately closed.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was otherwise. I don't have a computer with me right now to check. Does the `dev.off` command close both devices or just the X11? Or is it just because the script terminates after the plot?

Comment: @Eumenedies I don't know. In RStudio, `dev.off` does not close the plot. So it is rather because the script terminates.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your time and info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168040/discussion-between-eumenedies-and-stephane-laurent).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent What does it take if I wanted to save the image in two different directories? Repeat the code?

Comment: @RaimibinKarim Yes, I think so. The `png` function takes only one filename as argument. Otherwise use `file.copy` since this is the same image.