# R Programming on plot to label the axes

Tags: r

Create a plot with cars dataset and attribute speed along the X axis and distance in y axis .
Label the axes.

I have done this programming still there is some problem:

```r
plot(cars,xlab="speed",ylab="distance")
```

Even though everything seems correct the terminal doesn't move to the next part

Comment: Are you getting an error message or the plot doesn't show in a device window?

Comment: If my answer will be correct then the environment will automatically allow me to continue further but it says that complete the task which means it isn't

Answer (score 1):

What environment are you using? I was able to execute the following code and produce the plot you want using both RStudio and R directly in the terminal.

```
library(MASS)

plot(cars, xlab="Distance", ylab="Speed")
```

If you're running straight from the terminal then you'll need to specify a window to pop up. The following question has an answer that outlines what to do depending on your operating system:

[How to pop up the graphics window from Rscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544779/how-to-pop-up-the-graphics-window-from-rscript)

So, for example, if you don't have your system configured to automatically open the plot window, and you're running on a mac, the following code will produce what you want directly from running R in the terminal:

```
library(MASS)
X11()
plot(cars, xlab="Distance", ylab="Speed")
```

Comment: I was doing this in katacoda training. I was able to do the same in the rstudio but not in Katakoda

Comment: I see. I am only vaguely familiar with Katakoda, do you have an editor where you can write and save scripts, and then a command line from which you can run them? Or are you only working with the command line?