# Library loads with R but not with Rscript

Tags: r, rscript, r-library

I am getting the following error when I try to load a library in R using Rscript.

When I run

`Rscript -e "library(coexpp)"`

I get the following error

`Error in x$.self$finalize() : expecting an external pointer`

I am able to load the library, however, inside R interactively.

Comment: You may need to set an environment variable pointing to your ../Resources/library/

Comment: .libPaths() is same in both cases

Comment: 1. When you use R interactively, what is the version? And when you use it with Rscript, is the same version used? 2. Does loading WGCNA work, and does the error persist when you load that package before you load `coexpp`?

Comment: This is a duplicate -- you need to _manually_ add `library(methods)` as `Rscript` would not load this by default -- this has finally been changed in R, but not yet in the version  you run. Another existing answer of mine showing that is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297634/cv-glmnet-works-in-rstudio-but-not-rscript/34297635#34297635). There are more.

Comment: `library(methods)` didn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: `R CMD BATCH` as suggested in the linked question, works. Thanks